# iOS: Target 'Log4Cocoa' of project 'Log4Cocoa' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libLog4Cocoa.a'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I'm trying to implement [Log4Cocoa](https://github.com/endSly/Log4Cocoa) as framework. 
but I'm getting this error:

```
    Target 'Log4Cocoa' of project 'Log4Cocoa' was rejected as an
    implicit dependency for 'libLog4Cocoa.a' 
    because its architectures 'i386' didn't contain all required
architectures 'i386 x86_64'
```

I can not figure out what is wrong with the project.

Any of you have any idea of why of this error?

I'll really appreciate your help